# data-toggle doesn't work jquery

Tags: jquery

Why is my dropdown menu not working? When I click on the button, there is no dropdown menu. I have no idea what the problem is. Maybe something with including jquery or bootstrap?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Softuni Blog</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
    <script  src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top text-uppercase ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Softuni Blog</a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe it has to do with the space in your `.navbar- collapse ` should be `.navbar-collapse`

Comment: where is the jquery code?

Comment: You haven't included the bootstrap CSS file...

Comment: why such an out-of-date jQuery version? It's not even the latest in the 1.x branch, and unless you need to support IE8 or less, then 2.x or 3.x would be better

Comment: add screenshots and JS code as well